# Word pagination - excessive gap

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-word-2011

I am working on my resume on my Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) and Microsoft Word 2011.

On the second page of the resume is a gap such that I can't pull up the rest of my work history to the top of the page.  It looks really unprofessional. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hello Mick, maybe you could take a little screenshot and add it to your question. That way other users may be able to help you faster.

Comment: The gap could be caused by a blank page header being defined, and if so you should be able to delete or at least minimize it. Turning on View Text Boundaries in Print View can be very helpful in determining what's going on as well as Show Formatting Marks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have had that happen to me, I save the document as text only, then open it again and redo the formatting - Sure is quicker than trying to find out what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have paragraph spacing set to high. Try changing spacing before and after to 0 in paragraph properties.